# Pascal's Triangle Formatting Issue for "n" Rows (Java)

Tags: java, loops, format

I am trying to create and properly format Pascal's Triangle where the user inputs a value "n" for the number of rows that will be output.  The issue here is getting the proper format past 13 rows.  I am thinking the issue resides with the %4d since numbers that exceed the 13th row will tend to need more than 4 spaces.  I just don't know how I can implement something like that for an (essentially) infinite value of n (I know the limitations of the double variable, but I hope you understand what I mean).  Also, I would prefer a solution that did not implement the use of arrays.

```
double n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int number = 1;
        System.out.printf("%" + (n - i) * 2 + "s", "");
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.printf("%4d", number);
            number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Why not start with the last row first. That way, you get a better idea of the max space you will need. Put each row into a stack and print out the stack until empty.

Comment: Pascal is a programming language.  Please don't use the Pascal tag unless you have a question about that language.  If you hover over a tag, StackOverflow will tell you what the tag means.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using a matrix...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type N: ");
        pascalTriangle(scanner.nextInt());
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void pascalTriangle(final int N) {
        int[][] triangle = new int[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    triangle[i][0] = 1;
                else
                    triangle[i][j] = triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j];
                System.out.print(triangle[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type N: 13
1   
1   1   
1   2   1   
1   3   3   1   
1   4   6   4   1   
1   5   10  10  5   1   
1   6   15  20  15  6   1   
1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1   
1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1   
1   9   36  84  126 126 84  36  9   1   
1   10  45  120 210 252 210 120 45  10  1   
1   11  55  165 330 462 462 330 165 55  11  1   
1   12  66  220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66  12  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a better solution using a mathematical formula instead of arrays:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type N: ");
        pascalTriangle(scanner.nextInt());
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void pascalTriangle(final int N) {
        int row, num;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            num = 1;
            row = i + 1;
            for (int col = 0; col <= i; col++) {
                if (col > 0)
                    num = num * (row - col) / col;
                System.out.print(num + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type N: 13
1   
1   1   
1   2   1   
1   3   3   1   
1   4   6   4   1   
1   5   10  10  5   1   
1   6   15  20  15  6   1   
1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1   
1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1   
1   9   36  84  126 126 84  36  9   1   
1   10  45  120 210 252 210 120 45  10  1   
1   11  55  165 330 462 462 330 165 55  11  1   
1   12  66  220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66  12  1
```